# How to have ALL Android Studio 3.5 source files NOT be in usual location in project tree but on a separate drive

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I'd like to keep my java source files (i.e., those that I will create or edit) on an external or a second internal drive, separated from the hundreds (or thousands) of files created during compilation. Let all project files be on drive `C:` except my editable source files.

Let's call the drive to put the sources on `X:`.

Here is a normal AS 3.5 project tree for `C:\users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\myProject`:[image]

and here is the `...\app\src` folder:[image]

I don't want to have the entire `app` folder on drive `X:` because `app` (notably `app\build\intermediates`) will contain hundreds (likely thousands) of files and folders.

I just want the very small `...\app\src` folder on `X:` partly for the purpose of having a 90% smaller backup size for projects.

It seems like this would be a common thing for an AS user to want, but lots of Googling hasn't shown much in the way of concrete specific examples.

For better or worse, here's what my `build.gradle` file has (d)evolved into:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript
{
    repositories
    {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    }
}

android
{
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig
    {
        applicationId "com.dslomer64.sqhell"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes
    {
        release
        {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies
{
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
}
```

I didn't write any of it. I only took what compilation produced, changing only whatever the latest build error caused me to change.

Yes, I need to learn `gradle`. But not today, please.

I suspect `sourceSets` may be where to stick something like `X:\AndroidStudioProjects\myProject\src`, where `src` will contain the `main` folder shown in the second picture. And I gather that the 'src' or 'srcdir' keyword should precede that path.

***EDIT***
Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
sourceSets
{
    main
    {
        java { srcDir 'X:\\AndroidStudioProjects\\myProject\\src\\main' }
    }
}
```

*End Edit*

Surely there are a relatively few lines inside a new block in my existing `build.gradle` file that could be added to accomplish the task. Surely someone on SO has done this very thing. Please provide or share the required block and any other changes that may also be required.

I will most certainly appreciate the gift.